# append() in js for loop is not working properly

Tags: javascript, append

I'm learning js and I ran into a problem with the append()
When using an append in a for loop, the append method is executed only for the last item

```js
let item = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
let delIcon = document.createElement('a')
delIcon.innerHTML = 'del'
for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  let newItem = item[i].append(delIcon)
  console.log(newItem);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
</ul>
```

and the result is :

```
1
2
3
4del
```

why append() is only works for last element?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+why+only+appends+one+OR+once+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You only create one `a` element so it only append one. You need to create `a` element in every loops.
This may work for you

```
let item = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for(let i = 0;i<item.length;i++){
  let delIcon = document.createElement('a')
  delIcon.innerHTML = 'del'
  let newItem = item[i].append(delIcon)
  console.log(newItem);
}
```

and the result is :

```
1del
2del
3del
4del
```

Comment: why i have to write createElement() inside the loop?

Comment: You need to write `createElement()` inside the loop to create `a` element in every loops